# ViewPager with setOffscreenPageLimit hiding my initial Activity title

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-toolbar, android-titlebar

I'm using a standard ViewPager inside an Activity. Very basic stuff:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/new_teal"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, in my acitivity's code, I have an OnPageChangeListener which I'm using to switch the title in the toolbar whenever the viewpager's views are paged through.

I'm also calling setTitle(...) to set the title for the initial screen.

The issue with all of this is that I'm setting setOffscreenPageLimit(...), and when I do, that initial call to setTitle(...) gets overridden or hidden or something. The title just disappears!!!

If I remove setOffscreenPageLimit(...), then the entire thing misbehaves, as expected.

Any ideas???

Comment: Can you show us your Activity's code?

Answer (score 0):

For a effective solution we need to see your fragment's code but if you do not set a offScreenPageLimit to a view pager it create 1 previous and one next fragment of your current fragment. All these three fragments gets created and calls default fragment lifecycle methods such as onCreate, onViewCreated and etc.

If you are changing your title in one of your fragments which will be created when you set offScreenPageLimit to 2 or more, you can get this behave.

For example let's say your current Fragment is C and your view pager contains a b C d e and you change title in a or e fragments or other fragments in second or more position.

I hope this'll help you.